# mysql SET and UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace a column value based off values from other columns, but I keep getting syntax errors. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I've tired:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id_1` =164 and `id_2` = 6
SET `id_1` = (188|164)
WHERE `id_1` = 164 AND `id_2` = 6 
UPDATE `table`
```

This gives me a syntax near SET.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id_1` = 164 AND `id_2` = 6
UPDATE `table`
SET `id_1` = 188
WHERE `id_2` = 6
```

This gives me an error for everything below UPDATE.

Comment: It's probably best to look up the UPDATE statement syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the UPDATE and SELECT both within a one query.

Execute the both query separately like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id_1` = 164 AND `id_2` = 6;
```

And then execute:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `id_1` = 188
WHERE `id_2` = 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the end of statement punctuation ';' after your select statement. After you do a SELECT you have to end that statement before you start your next statement (the UPDATE):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id_1` = 164 AND `id_2` = 6; -- semicolon goes here
UPDATE `table`
SET `id_1` = 188
WHERE `id_2` = 6; -- and another semicolon goes here
```

That will get rid of your syntax error.